How to change the duty cycle of a square wave without introducing any change in the pulse generaror in MATLAB simulink?
I have four square waves S1, S2, S3 and S4. All have 50% duty cycle. When S1 is on S2 is off
(vice versa) and when S4 is on S3 is off (vice versa). I want to change the duty cycle of S1 and S3 to more than 50 % and the duty cycle of S2 and S4 to less than 50% of the period (as shown in the figure), without introducing any change in the pulse generator, i.e. the change has to be done outside the pulse generator.How do I do it in MATLAB simulink? Image of the pulses in required fashion//Image of the pulse generator block
The pulses are generated using a sawtooth generator, hit crossing block and SR flip-flop.

Not exactly sure what you mean by "outside the pulse generator". The "PWM" block has an input that allows you to change the duty cycle. Have you tried that as opposed to the "sawtooth generator" (a.k.a. "Repeating Sequence")?

Can I change the duty cycle by connecting any other blocks to the signal? I don't want to change the duty cycle using a PWM block or by changing the sawtooth generator. The generator is already very complex. I have attached a picture of the signal generator. I want to change the duty cycle right before they enter the 2 muxes, that I have marked.

What you need is something like a comparator circuit in electronics: the input is for example your sawtooth signal and a second input is a signal that is going to be a variable reference. A comparator will output 1 (or high) when the sawtooth signal > reference and 0 if not.
What you need is two comparators (S1 = output1, S3 = inverse of output1), or four comparators if you want to overdo it (inverse of output is far easier than using a separate second comparator for an inverse signal).
